# Jackson + Gson + Retrofit Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: android, json, jackson, gson, retrofit2

I know this has been asked a lot but, none of the question I've found solve my especific problem.

Here is my JSON

**[JSON URL][1]**

```
[
  {      
    "unit":"IMECA",
    "value":29,
  },
  {
    "unit":"IMECA",
    "value":43,
  }
]
```

this is my DTO

**Zona.java**

```
  public class Zona {
  private String unit;
  private int value;

  public String getUnit() {
    return unit;
  }

  public void setUnit(String unit) {
    this.unit = unit;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(unit) + ": " + String.valueOf(value);
  }
}
```

and this is my Interface

**Api.java**

```
public interface Api {
  @GET("/data/heatmap_stations.json")
  Call<Zona> getZona();
}
```

I kind of understand ***why it happens*** , because is a JSON Array the response but Jackson + Gson are expecting a single JSON Object.

I tried creating a POJO like this:

**Zonas.java**

```
Public class Zonas extends ArrayList<Zona> {}
```

and changing the Call signature in the Interface and the Retrofit call, replacing the single DTO to the plural, (from Call< Zona > to Call< Zonas >, replacing the single class to the one who inherits ArrayList<>), but it simply does nothing, I mean, it didn't threw an Exception, but it didn't threw a response either.

Comment: There's a lot of duplicates about that exact error. Hint: you are returning a JSONArray, not a JSONObject, so you probably want `List<Zona>` in the Call

Comment: Also, Jackson and Gson perform the same operation, so I'm not sure why you have both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
public interface Api {
  @GET("/data/heatmap_stations.json")
  Call<Zona> getZona();
}
```

to

```
public interface Api {
  @GET("/data/heatmap_stations.json")
  Call<List<Zona>> getZona();
}
```

You are telling it to expect a single `Zona` object but it is returning an Array of `Zona` objects